# Rounding output of sine function with format

Tags: python, format

I'm trying to write a sine function that outputs answers going only to two decimal places. This is my code so far:

```
x=np.arange(0,190,10)
x_values=np.deg2rad(x)
y=np.sin(x_values)
y_values={":.2f"}.format(y)
print(y_values)
```

All the code through y works for me, when I do

```
print(y)
```

it outputs the correct values, but to like 10 decimal places, and I'd like to limit it to 2. I would like to do it using the .format notation, which I suck at. I'm getting an error that says "'set' object has no attribute 'format'," so there's some kind of fundamental misunderstanding I have about exactly how .format works. Is it only meant for strings? I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

I did have a successful result using this:

```
y_values=[ '%.2f' % elem for elem in y ]
```

However, I'd like to see if it's possible to do it with .format. Thank you!

Comment: "I'm getting an error that says "'set' object has no attribute 'format'," so there's some kind of fundamental misunderstanding I have about exactly how .format works. Is it only meant for strings?" Yes; this is a simple typo - you **don't want** a set; you get one because you put the `{}` - which are supposed to be part of the string - outside the string. Before posting, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing solutions and to [carefully study the code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to look for simple problems.

Comment: Put another way: it is the same problem as if you had written `%'.2f' % elem` and wondered why it causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
y_values=[ '{:.2f}'.format(elem) for elem in y ]
```

I prefer f strings:

```
y_values=[ f'{elem:.2f}' for elem in y ]
```

The problem with your code was that the curly braces were outside the quotes and that `y` is a list. Moving the braces and using a list comprehension (as you showed in your last bit of code) are the two changes that fixed the issues you had.

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not answer questions that are common duplicates and/or boil down to simple typos. The only thing that was wrong in OP's code was the placement of the `{}`. I **really** should not have to explain something like this to someone with your level of experience.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: That wasn't the only problem. The variable `y` contains a list. The solution was to correct the typo and combine the techniques the OP tried. I shouldn't be chastised for completely solving a poster's actual problem.

Comment: OP *already demonstrated* the technique for handling the list. But even if that were missing information, it is another common duplicate. Stack Overflow is **not there** to "completely solve posters' actual problems"; it is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am quite new to Python, I only started two weeks ago, so these kinds of things are sometimes hard for me to catch.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a universal vectorized function for this:

```py
v_format = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: f'{x:.{y}f}')

# v_format(1, 2) returns
# array('1.00', dtype='<U4')

# v_format([15.2445, 154.5647, 35.6785], 2) returns
# array(['15.24', '154.56', '35.68'], dtype='<U6')

# v_format([15.2445, 154.5647, 35.6785], 4) returns
# array(['15.2445', '154.5647', '35.6785'], dtype='<U8')

# v_format([1.23, 3.456, 7.8910], [1, 2, 3]) returns
# array(['1.2', '3.46', '7.891'], dtype='<U5')
```

Work for every array with any numbers in it (even with complex ones).

* (If you need you can convert an array into a list or a tuple)

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not answer questions that are common duplicates and/or boil down to simple typos. The only thing that was wrong in OP's code was the placement of the `{}`. Also, it makes no sense to bust out Numpy for this, or to generalize in this way. Please do not invent questions to answer that OP did not ask.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The OP is already using Numpy as evidenced in the code posted in the question.